# accessing public object property for OpenAL buffer

Tags: c++, object, openal

I created an object with two public properties:

```
class Sound {
public:
    unsigned int * source; 
    unsigned int * buffer;
}
```

Now I want to access to these variables but I'm stucked.. the compiler compiles without errors, but when I do something like

```
Sound *s = new Sound();
alGenBuffers(1, s->buffer);
alGenSources(1, s->source);
```

It throws errors.. passing in those functions a simple unsigned int * variable it works, but I want an object oriented style.

What I'm doing wrong? I even tried with getter and setter, but same error is thrown..

Thanks

EDIT: **sorry I just did a typo while copying my code here, it was s->buffer and s->source**.

Error thrown:
Not handled exception in 0x00894E93 in project.exe 0xC0000005; Violation access while reading 0x00000000

Comment: `Sound *s = new Sound();` is a bad idea already (also having those pointer members in the `Sound` class).

Comment: what is the best practice?

Comment: _"what is the best practice?"_ Depends on what `alGenBuffers()` actually is. Are you trying to wrap a c-style API?

Comment: I'm trying to use OpenAL API. With simple variables it works perfectly.. but the problem is when I'm storing variables into an Object

Comment: The exact error messages would provide useful clues for determining what's wrong. You should add them to the question.

Comment: I just provided the error but I think that it is an error due to reading an empty buffer

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ however I need those pointers, I need a class to store those variables, then I will decorate class with some functions (either I would have used struct)

Comment: @greenfox I should have said _public pointer members_. The whole point of OOP is data encapsulation, and c-style functions to initialize them can be calle from your constructor function or other public functions of your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a null pointer to each function. Instead, you want a pointer to an `unsigned int` variable which will be used to store the result. (In general, they want a pointer to an array; but in this case you're just creating one of each, so a single variable for each will suffice.)

```
class Sound {
public:
    unsigned int source; 
    unsigned int buffer;
};

alGenBuffers(1, &s->buffer);
alGenSources(1, &s->source);
```

Comment: Just tried your solution, it runs the part of generating buffers, but later I have to call another function "playSound" which do the following: alSourcePlay(s->source); but checking with breakpoints I found that buffer and source are empty when calling that function.. :\ I have no clue

Comment: @greenfox: I'm afraid I don't know enough about OpenAL to help you debug that. Perhaps you might ask another question, showing exactly what you're doing, and explaining what you mean by "empty".

Comment: alright I just instanced the sound before entering the function, not inside, and its OK. It clearly runs.. but there is no sound :( I think I just need pointers
However thanks so much for helping me

Comment: OK, I just made the code works. Your answer put me in right way,  hence I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access uninitialized pointers, meaning you are trying to dereference a null pointer, those pointers needs to be initialized first, for more information:
[What is a class constructor?](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm)

and you should also read this:
[Important points to Note using a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523361/2363706)

In any case puting your member variables in the public section is bad practice and you should use getter and setter:
[Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)